# Executing Commands within Configuration - Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

We have a JSON configuration file, where each item in that file is an ingestion task. One of the fields is called tableFilter where tableFilter contains a condition to filter the table by, for example `someDateColumnInSAP GTE '20210204'` what we'd like to do is `someDateColumnInSAP GTE formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyyMMdd')` however, this does not work. The error is: `A condition specified at runtime has an unexpected format` is there a way to get ADF functions to work within a string?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [CONCAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#concat) function when you are combing string values with functions in expression.

`@concat('someDateColumnInSAP GTE ',formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyyMMdd'))`

[image]

Result:

[image]